# Google spreadsheets auto fill formula with form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to get my Google form submissions set up so I can produce a PDF with Auto Crat with the right information since my form has yes and no questions.

I need 4 different columns to auto fill with my different but similar formula below as my first sheet is filled using IMPORTRANGE from my Form submissions master sheet. If there is an easier way to do all this please let me know since I am really new to Google formulas.

`=if(Sheet1!P3="Yes", (CONCATENATE("My yes answer "&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"<b>Employee name:</b> "&Sheet1!Q3&CHAR(10)&"<b>Location (room number where the employee will be during the emergency):</b> "&Sheet1!R3&CHAR(10)&"<b>Telephone number (room where the employee will be during the emergency):</b> "&Sheet1!S3&CHAR(10)&"<b>Critical operation:</b> "&Sheet1!T3)), "it is the no response")`

[Here is the Master](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DK8vysY8V9vJ6URBOmuj0qXTnrc0g-N7ZeUxzhh0BL0/edit?usp=sharing)

[Here is the two sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jM8n0N8UKD-g6Pz2R6Tr8GsIksKkYEwHy3MqDtIzpcI/edit?usp=sharing) I am using. The first pulls in the information and the second sheet is where I use my formulas.

Comment: Anyone out there that can give me some sort of idea how to build a script to make the rows auto fill with the formulas in certain columns upon importrange from the form submissions? Please I really need some help on this one.

Comment: You want values from different columns to be concatenated together, and then save to a different location?  I guess the end result is 4 new columns?  What file and sheet do you want the end result to be in?

Comment: HI Sandy, I would want it to end up in the second sheet on the "Here are the two sheets" and thank you for your time. The File can be from the Master sheet or sheet two mentioned earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get an add-on to sheets called copyDown to copy the formula down the rows for me. This helped me to keep it all on one sheet instead of having two sheets so I could use AutoCrat for compiling my PDF correctly. Thank you for all the help in solving this issue.